# Resque schedueler loading jobs but not enqueing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, resque-scheduler

I have a schedule and it is defined in the resque.rake like this:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'
task 'resque:setup' => :environment



namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'


  end

  task :setup_schedule => :setup do
    require 'resque-scheduler'
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = Rails.env
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file('config/tweet_schedule.yml')
    require 'tweet_sender.rb'
    end

task :scheduler => :setup_schedule


end
```

The schedele tweet_schedule.yml

```
tweet_sender:
  cron: "57 7 * * *"
  class: "TweetSender"
  queue: tweets_queue
  args: tweet_id
  rails_env: development
  description: "This job sends daily tweets from the content db"
```

Whenever I run (and the redis-server, rails s, load the workers through

```
bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE='*' --trace
```

)

bundle exec rake environment resque:scheduler I get the following output

```
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2017-04-14T09:14:49+02:00: Starting
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2017-04-14T09:14:49+02:00: Loading Schedule
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2017-04-14T09:14:49+02:00: Scheduling tweet_sender 
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2017-04-14T09:14:49+02:00: Schedules Loaded
Passing 'info' command to redis as is; administrative commands cannot be effectively namespaced and should be called on the redis connection directly; passthrough has been deprecated and will be removed in redis-namespace 2.0 (at sucesfully/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:60:in `method_missing')
Passing 'script' command to redis as is; administrative commands cannot be effectively namespaced and should be called on the redis connection directly; passthrough has been deprecated and will be removed in redis-namespace 2.0 (at /home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:60:in `method_missing')
```

So I assume it is loading my schedusucesfullyle but it looks like it is not getting enqued (I have ignored the namespace warning so far)

The schedule shows up in the resque-scheduler web ui and whenever I manually set it of through the web interface button the job gets executed successfully. Any ide why it does not load correctly?

[image: Queue now button used to set of jobs]

Comment: Pressing "enter" after I see these messages helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end after a lot of trying around I found that resque scheduler was not picking up my cron definition.

after changing the 5* cron to a 6*cron

```
5* cron cron: "57 7 * * *"
5* cron cron: "15 57 7 * * *"
```

The job now gets scheduled every hour. I have yet to figure out how schedule the job ever day because the standard cron syntax does not seem to work

```
minute (0-59),
|      hour (0-23),
|      |       day of the month (1-31),
|      |       |       month of the year (1-12),
|      |       |       |       day of the week (0-6 with 0=Sunday).
|      |       |       |       |       command
0      2       *       *       0,4
```